# Does the IdSNMP component in Indy 10 support SNMP version 2c?

Tags: delphi-7, indy10

I have written a simple "Get" request in Delphi7 using the Indy10 TIdSNMP component but it returns an empty reply.

The target device's Agent doesn't support v1 SNMP so I have configured it for SNMP version 2c.

I know that the OID I am requestin is correct as I used a MIB Browser to obtain it from the same device using its MIB.

I vaguely recall seeing a comment on the forums that Indy 9 only supported SNMP version 1, so I am wondering that's still the case for Indy 10?

Answer (score 1):

At this time, Indy 10 still does not support SNMP versions above v1. It is on the TODO list:

[#56: Update TIdSNMP to support newer SNMP versions](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/56)